# Remove additionally installed packages (from Kontact)

Tags: apt, kontact

I wanted to try Kontact, but that automatically installed another bunch of packages. After deciding that I didn't really like Kontact, I removed it with

```
sudo apt-get remove kontact
```

but that doesn't remove all the other programs which were installed with kontact, like korganizer, knotes etc...

How do I find which packages were automatically installed in the process of installing a certain application (in this case kontact) so that I can remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `autoremove` sub command:

```
sudo apt autoremove kontact
```

From `man apt`:

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed as
>              dependencies changed or the package(s) needing them were removed in the meantime.

You can also use `--purge` to remove config files too:

```
sudo apt autoremove kontact --purge
```

If `autoremove` does to work for you so you should do it manually, run something like:

```
grep kontact -A10 /var/log/apt/history.log
```

to see which packages are installed by `kontact` then remove them manually.